# Hasvalue in switch statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fill in an existing variable with some value out of different existing variabels, prioritizing to the first filled value variable.

What i mean with it is this:

I have variable A that needs to be setted from 4 other variabels: B, C, D and E. All 5 are nullable string. But i only want to set it priority in order from B to E.

This is an example i want to get:

```
switch(HasValue())
{
   case(B):
        A = B;
        break;
   case(C):
        A = C;
        break;
   case(D):
        A = D;
        break;
   case(E):
        A = E;
        break;
   default:
        A = string.empty;
        break;
```

So if variable D has value, set A as D. If B and D has both value, pick B.

But switch is expecting a value, not an statement or method.

I've tried to make it with a lot of if else statement, but that gets really big overtime. I need something more compact where i can add new value's later on.

Is there a way to achieve this or are there other better ways to solve it?

Comment: have you tried using if else statement and the &&, || operators?

Comment: `A = B ?? C ?? D ?? E;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try chaining `??` operator:

```
 A = B ?? C ?? D ?? E ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `HasValue` is some method you have defined for string you can put them in collection and use LINQ:

```
A = new [] { B, C, D, E }.FirstOrDefault(s => s.HasValue()) ?? string.Empty;
```